# Will Cat6 make a difference

Tags: ethernet, layer1, cabling, cable, utp

I have 7 rooms wired with Cat5e. I plan to attach the other end of the cables to a GigaBit switch (Netgear GS108). This leaves one port on the switch. I will attach my router to the remaining port. I will attach my router to my modem.

My question is: 
Will making the cable between the router and switch and the cable between the router and modem a CAT6, as opposed to CAT 5e, cable make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cat5e is fine for Gigabit Ethernet, so no it would not make a difference